# Display 360 Image in Silverlight 3.0 (Not Panorama)

Tags: silverlight, image, graphics, 3d

I have a lot of images taken from a 360 camera which I would like to be able to display in Silverlight 3. They are NOT regular panorama images. The camera which took the image actually creates a distorted jpeg that becomes undistorted once wrapped around a sphere as a texture. I have desktop software that will allow viewing of the image (not just side-to-side, but straight up, down, etc.) and I need to try to get the same functionality in Silverlight. It is very similar to Google StreetView.

What I think I need is to create a sphere, wrap the jpeg on the sphere as a texture, then put the "camera" inside the sphere. I doubt this is possible in Silverlight, but perhaps there is a way to simulate this?

So far, Google searches aren't bringing anything up. Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure out how to do this? Are there any existing projects that do this?

An example of a typical image is [here.](http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/5640/113014255138.jpg)

Comment: There is not going to be a "ready made" solution to do this in Silverlight (unless someone has done it before and shared the code somewhere which is probably not the case). I would look into using pixel shaders to perform the distortion on the image.

Comment: Pixel shaders would be perfect, but it looks as if they only work on still images in Silverlight. If my understanding is correct, it wouldn't be possible to move the camera around with pixel shaders.

Answer (score 1):

These *might* help you out (probably not).  They are 3d engines for silverlight, but they will probably wrap the image **outside** of the sphere instead of inside, which is probably what you need.

**Kit3D** http://www.codeplex.com/Kit3D

**Balder** http://www.codeplex.com/Balder

Another, possibly more promising option, would be to use javascript.  So far you've probably researched how to do this in Silverlight, but you might do some similar searching for using javascript for this.  There may be an option out there already, and since Silverlight can interopt with Javascript, you might be in luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your gonna have to map the [texture](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/spheremap.htm) to a [sphere](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/mapping/spheretx.htm) then, like you said. But afaik silverlight 3 doesn't support hardware accelerated 3d.

So your options are:

- Try and find a silverlight software 3d library ([Like this](http://axeleratesl3d.codeplex.com/))
- Write your own software rasterizer ([multi page guide)](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article795.asp)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try cropping a window from the image and display it. if the user want to go right, move the window right and crop. if the user wants to go left, move the window left and crop. to zoom out, expand the window, to zoom in make the window smaller. if you move the frame far right then stitch the image data from the left side.

You might need to modify the image to eliminate the distortion, this shouldn't be too hard and depends on the camera lens focal length.

Don't try mapping the image to a sphere, it is much harder.

Comment: Actually modifying the image sounds pretty hard, unless you know of an easy way to do it. This image was actually generated by several cameras stitched together.

Comment: You don't really need to crop but copy a window from an image to another image source. Think of it as having a small frame with your image as a background. All you need to do is move the background in a wanted direction.

Answer (score 0):

At https://hdviewsl.codeplex.com it says that HD View SL (Silverlight version) supports
"orthographic (2D), with wrapping for 360-degree panoramas"

Also you could try to port PtViewer source code to Silverlight from Java if no one else has

UPDATE:
VRLight might be the solution in your case:
http://vrlight.thecloudsite.net/
http://vrlight.thecloudsite.net/tutorial.html
http://ivrpa.org/blog/3651/vrlight_vredit_20

Its author (Jurgen Eidt) is also making cPicture (http://cpicture.thecloudsite.net/index.en.html), if you can't find him from the VRLight site, try from the cPicture one, or try from his blog at IVRPA website (http://ivrpa.org/blog/3651), which seems to have recent posts

Comment: That's pretty close, but not quite what I'm looking for. My 360 images aren't normal panorama images - they allow you to look straight up as well. [Sample image](http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/5640/113014255138.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried your image URL with http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/HDView/Preview/ (select the HD View SL tab)? Tried your URL there, but the 2nd tab doesn't seem to get activated with that one. Maybe you should try the links from the side that use .xml files and create such an xml file yourself too (maybe based on the Zoomify samples, not sure) to try out